# Making Table row focus and loose focus using event handlers using c# in wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop-application

I have a table placed in the FlowDocument. I am adding data to the table dynamically using c# at the backend. I have attached the event handler for focusing a row but I am facing issue with removing the focus if the user click anywhere besides that row.

My XAML code is this:

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Width="auto">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Table x:Name="feedTable">
                        <Table.Columns>
                            <TableColumn Width="*"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="3*"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="2*"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="4*"/>
                            <TableColumn Width="*"/>
                        </Table.Columns>
                        <TableRowGroup>
                            <TableRow>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">On</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">Feed Link</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">Site</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">Title</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                    <Paragraph FontSize="14pt" FontWeight="Bold">Feeds</Paragraph>
                                </TableCell>
                            </TableRow>
                        </TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRowGroup x:Name="feedTableRowGroup">

                        </TableRowGroup>
                    </Table>
                </FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

This is how I am adding the data to the table at the backend after getting it from the db

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            feedTableRowGroup.Rows.Add(new TableRow());
            var currentRow = feedTableRowGroup.Rows[feedTableRowGroup.Rows.Count - 1];

            CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
            checkBox.Tag = ((int)data.Rows[i]["id"]).ToString();
            checkBox.IsChecked = (byte)data.Rows[i]["is_enabled"] == 1 ? true : false;

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(checkBox);

            int maxChars = 25;
            string link = (string)data.Rows[i]["link"];
            link = link.Length <= maxChars ? link : link.Substring(0, maxChars) + "....";

            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(paragraph));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(link))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run((string)data.Rows[i]["site_name"]))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run((string)data.Rows[i]["title"]))));
            currentRow.Cells.Add(new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(((int)data.Rows[i]["items_count"]).ToString()))));

            currentRow.MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(FocusTableRow);

        }
```

The "currentRow.MouseDown" add the focus to the row when I click on it but now whenever I click on another empty space I want to remove this focus.

I have already created the eventhadnlers for adding focus and removing them and I am adding the focus but now I need a way to remove this focus

```
private void FocusTableRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       sender.GetType().GetProperty("Background").SetValue(sender, Brushes.LightGray);    
    }

    private void NonFocusTableRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sender.GetType().GetProperty("Background").SetValue(sender, Brushes.White);
    }
```

Is there any eventhadler I can use to assign to remove this focus from the row?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean by "focus" for a row since all your code is doing is highlighting the row with a different Background color (Focus means something different when speaking about GUIs). But assuming that is the intention and assuming only one row can be "focused" at a time, there are a number of ways to accomplish what you describe. I wouldn't necessarily do it this way but without knowing more about your code & data from what you've given...

First, when you highlight a specified row, turn "off" the highlight on all the other rows...

```
private void FocusTableRow (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    sender.GetType ().GetProperty ("Background").SetValue (sender, Brushes.LightGray);

    foreach (var row in feedTableRowGroup.Rows) {
        if (row != sender) {
            row.GetType ().GetProperty ("Background").SetValue (row, Brushes.White);
        }
    }

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I also added the e.Handled = true to signal we handled the mouse down event and stop anyone else from handling it.

Then add a MouseDown handler to the feedTable (either in ctor or where you are initializing the data) to catch when clicking outside the rows and turn "off" all the row highlights...

```
feedTable.MouseDown += FeedTable_MouseDown;
```

...

```
private void FeedTable_MouseDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var row in feedTableRowGroup.Rows) {
        row.GetType ().GetProperty ("Background").SetValue (row, Brushes.White);
    }
}
```

again, not the way I would have done it and probably not the most WPF-friendly method, but it will work with what you've given us. This sounds like a good candidate for an MVVM architecture though it would require restructuring all your code a bit.

Comment: is there a way we can do this without manually unhighlighting all other rows?

Comment: If you are not locked into the FlowControlDocument set of classes, you could use one of the ItemsControl derived controls (i.e. ListView) or even the DataGrid. All of which have support for item selection (Multi AND Single row) and could be set up to do the highlighting automatically. There may be a way to do what you want using the TableRowGroup stuff but you are going beyond my knowledge of the Flow controls.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff for taking some time to answer my question. I will look further into it myself now.